# Can Azure Functions be written in Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm interested in using Azure Functions written in Python with Cosmos DB.

I saw a demo that was posted very recently (February 6th) that showed how to enable "Experimental Language Support" for AFs. Referencing the demo here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKGVRKtCp7Y) shows enabling this support option (as of 8 weeks ago) allowed Azure Functions to be written in Python.

I've followed the steps in the demo and I dont see Python as an option currently in my portal for HTTP Triggers. I'm wondering if support for Python has been dropped entirely or if there's a step I'm missing?

Please advise.

[image].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GitHub issue:[In-portal editing will be disabled for Python Functions](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/157).

> Python Function Apps on Functions v2, deployed to a Linux App Service
>   Plan allow in-portal file editing. This feature will be disabled
>   starting March 2019.

However you still could create the Python Function with [VS code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/getting-started) or  [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python).

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. I'll try out those options.